# checking user online or not play akka websockets

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, push-notification, akka

I am using play framework with Scala, Akka and websockets for frontend.
I want to build a notification socket for users. How can I connect actorRef with user id's and check whether the user is online or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of thinking 'whether the user is online or not', simply consider how websockets work. It is the frontend that needs to initiate the connection, so you automatically have an information that the user is online (more precisely, the web browser with the logged user).

I'd create one actor that is the coordinator of all other websocket actors (the actors that directly handle the websocket). This coordinator would have a map of userId to Seq[ActorRef]. It's a map where values are Seq[_] because a user can have multiple browser tabs open simultaneously (many actorRefs correspond to one userId) and you should handle that correctly. Whenever the client initiates the connection, a new websocket actor will be created. On the start of this actor you can register it to the coordinator actor (override preStart). When the websocket actor is destroyed (the websocket connection has been closed), unregister it. Registering/unregistering in the coordinator results in adding/removing this websocket's actorRef to the map.

To push a notification to the user (to the browsers in which the client is logged in), send a message to the coordinator actor containing the userId (and the rest of the notification of course). This actor will find all websocket actors in the map by the userId and forward the message to them.

The technical side of websockets in Play is described in the docs, which you've probably already seen -> https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWebSockets

*update*: Clarified that by `actorRefs` I meant Seq[ActorRef].

Comment: Instead of storing actorRefs to a coordinate actor can I store it to a database?

Comment: Sure, so instead of a coordinator actor, you'll have a service that is fetching actor refs for a given userid from database whenever you push some notification. Then you'll forward this notification to each of those actor refs.

Comment: I was trying to add a service but I'm getting exception while starting a service actor. Please give me some links so that i can understand it,Thank you